# How to change azure function local.settings.json based on solution configuration?

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We have a project that uses an azure service bus and we need to develop in parallel  so we need a solution that removes service bus a shared resource, so when developer A puts a message it doesn't affect developer B.

One solution it to duplicate the service bus so the new bus has same topics and subscriptions, but we need to change the ServiceBusTrigger Connection based on the Debug/DebugTest/Release active solution configuration, or find a way to change the ServiceBusTrigger Connection of multiple projects with a simple action.

Answer (score 2):

One of the several approaches you could take is to conditionally include a file that follows your convention. The file could be made optional (`optional: true`) and use a prefix of the environment you're in, communicated via an environment variable.

Pseudo code:

```cs
var envronment = Environment.GetVariable("EnvironmentName");

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
  // ...
  .AddJsonFile($"{environment}.appsettings.json", optional: true);
  Configuration = builder.Build();
```

This will allow you to load the override of the connection string per environment.

Comment: an azure function that has a service bus trigger expects a bus connection string and it loads it from local.settings.json by microsoft design, and I can't control that part; at the point I can write any code the function is already triggered, so the change needs to be done before the function method fires; we are already using code like you describe but in webapi projects

Comment: `ServiceBusTrigger` doesn't expect a connection string, but a connection string **name**. That means your local settings file can have different _values_ in different environments, but uses the same setting name. To influence the builder you would not load it from the function body, but rather from the startup code, which is designed to run before function is invoked.

Comment: ok, now makes sense; i think the issue was we were using some old style azure functions where we didn't have any startup file (and I didn't know it was possible to have one), so we didn't have access to a config builder or DI, having a startup changes things, thanks